# Resharper: Disable Attribute formatting?

Tags: c#, resharper

Resharper is driving me nuts. Is there no way to disable formatting of attributes completely?

Or more specifically, disable the **Place field attribute on same line** toggle completely. I don't want it to format it either way.

My code looks like this:

```
[Header("References")]
[SerializeField] private PlayerController playerController;
```

I want the Header attribute seperate because it affects all fields below it in the Unity editor inspector. But Resharper will only allow, with previously mentioned toggle, either:

```
[Header("References")]
[SerializeField]
private PlayerController playerController;
```

or

```
[Header("References")] [SerializeField] private PlayerController playerController;
```

If not, perhaps anyone smarter out there know a way to walk around this with a Custom Pattern?

Comment: Don't use Resharper?

Comment: I love everything else about Resharper, so I'd rather find a way around my problem than losing everything else.

Comment: @Jobot did you managed to find a way to solve this issue? Would be a great help to me too.

Comment: @StefanDoychev Unfortunately, no.